# Extracting Videos from tfrecord

Tags: video, tfrecord

I have a video dataset in tfrecord format.
I need to extract the actual videos from them.So that i can actually play the videos in a media player.  Any way to do it?

Comment: What does the dataset look like? Is it available somewhere online, or custom made?

Comment: Its youtube 8M dataset.

Comment: Did you make this dataset, or is it available online? If so, where? This info would help in answering the question

Comment: Its available online.. it's called YouTube 8M dataset.. you need to just search "YouTube 8M dataset" on Google. I have just downloaded it but it's in tfrecord format.. I need to get videos from tfrecord.. Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: the dataset contains the 'id' for the video which can be used to link back to the yT video itself - https://research.google.com/youtube8m/video_id_conversion.html